# sql - query join 2 table with 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry if the title is not related to my question. I don't know what's the correct title for this one.

So I have 5 tables in order to show related content to the user

1. Content (id, content, etc..) `Data related content`
2. ContentCategory (id, contentId, followCategoryId) `Data related content's categories`
3. ContentPublisher (id, contentId, followPublisherId) `Data related content's publishers`
4. FollowCategory (id, categoryId, userId (people who followed), etc..) `Data related user's followed categories`
5. FollowPublisher (id, publisherId, userId (people who followed), etc..) `Data related user's followed publishers`

How to show contents based on the user's followed categories and followed publishers, and if possible how to differentiate if the contents are from relation on followCategory or followPublisher

eg: Below is my query to show content based on user FollowPublisher, cmiiw

```
SELECT content.id, content.description, ...etc 
FROM followPublisher
LEFT JOIN publisher ON followPublisher.publisherId = publisher.id
LEFT JOIN contentPublisher ON publisher.id = contentPublisher.publisherId
RIGHT JOIN content ON contentPublisher.contentId = content.id
    WHERE followPublisher.userId = 8
ORDER BY content.created desc;
```

and below is my query to show content based on user followCategory

```
SELECT content.id, content.description, ...etc 
FROM followCategory
LEFT JOIN category ON followCategory.categoryId = category.id
LEFT JOIN contentCategory ON category.id = contentCategory.categoryId
RIGHT JOIN content ON contentCategory.contentId = content.id
    WHERE followCategory.userId = 8
ORDER BY content.created desc;
```

**How to combine these 2 queries to show content based on the user's followed categories and publishers at once or is there any better method instead of combining the queries?**

Comment: (1) You have tagged 2 different databases `mysql` and `postgressql` (2) Please share sample data in tables and expected output

Comment: @mysteryfollow . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: What is the table `publisher`? How many tables are there?

Comment: @forpas on the example the `publisher` table is to show the publisher info, there is a table `category` also tho show category info

Comment: Post the relations between the tables. In your code there is: `ON followPublisher.publisherId = contentPublisher.publisherId` but there is no column `publisherId` in the table `ContentPublisher `.

Comment: @forpas ahh sorry I mistyped it, the correct one is  `ON publisher.id = contentPublisher.publisherId`. There are some mistyped, I just updated it

Answer (score 0):

I THINK you want the following:

```
select content.* from content
LEFT JOIN contentPublisher ON content.id = contentPublisher.contentId 
LEFT JOIN Publisher ON contentPublisher.publisherId = publisher.id 
LEFT JOIN followPublisher ON publisher.id = followPublisher.publisherId
LEFT JOIN contentCategory ON content.id = contentCategory.contentId 
LEFT JOIN category ON contentCategory.categoryId = category.id 
LEFT JOIN followcategory ON category.id = followcategory.categoryId
where followPublisher.userId = 8 or followCategory.userId = 8
```

Comment: It only fetched the content from publisher in my case

Comment: what is the data in the followCategory table?

Comment: followCategory only has `id, categoryId and userId`. Turns out I come up with the union

Comment: @mysteryfollow What is the DATA, not the schema?

Comment: followCategory sample data

`insert into followCategory (id, categoryId, userId) values (1,1,8)`

`insert into followCategory (id, categoryId, userId) values (2,2,8)`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Union**

with 2 conditions

- Not use any table related (idk how to say it) in `order by` instead rename it using `as`. In my case the `order by content.created` should be changed to `content.created as contentCreated` and then we can use to `order by` it.
- Add default value column to indicate where the data comes from (in this case whether it's from `followPublisher` or `followCategory`)

query:

```
SELECT content.id, content.description, content.created as contentCreated ...etc, 'publisher' as type
FROM followPublisher
LEFT JOIN publisher ON followPublisher.publisherId = publisher.id
LEFT JOIN contentPublisher ON publisher.id = contentPublisher.publisherId
RIGHT JOIN content ON contentPublisher.contentId = content.id
    WHERE followPublisher.userId = 8
UNION
SELECT content.id, content.description, content.created as contentCreated ...etc, 'category' as type
FROM followCategory
LEFT JOIN category ON followCategory.categoryId = category.id
LEFT JOIN contentCategory ON category.id = contentCategory.categoryId
RIGHT JOIN content ON contentCategory.contentId = content.id
    WHERE followCategory.userId = 8
ORDER BY contentCreated desc;
```